# Двумерный массив + parseInt Java

Tags: java

```
public TileMap(String s, int tileSize) {
        this.tileSize = tileSize;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));

            mapWidth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            mapHeigth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            map = new int[mapHeigth][mapWidth];

            String delimiter = "\\s+";

            for(int row = 0; row < mapHeigth; row++){
                String line = br.readLine();
                String[] tokens = line.split(delimiter);

                for(int col = 0; col < mapWidth; col++){
                    map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[col]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

Помогите разобраться с `map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[col]);`. Не понимаю, что здесь происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создается квадратная матрица размера mapWidth на mapHeigth:

```
mapWidth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
mapHeigth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
map = new int[mapHeigth][mapWidth];
```

Внешний цикл для обхода всех строк матрицы:

```
String delimiter = "\\s+";
for (int row = 0; row < mapHeigth; row++)
```

Считываем из файла строку которую нам необходимо пропарсить:

```
String line = br.readLine();
```

Строка делится на массив по символу-разделителю:

```
String[] tokens = line.split(delimiter);
```

Внутренний цикл для обхода каждого элемента каждой строки:

```
for (int col = 0; col < mapWidth; col++)
```

В двухмерный массив (матрица) с индексами row col (row - номер строки) (col-номер элемента в строке) записывается число int пропаршеное из входной строки `tokens[col]`:

`map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[col]);`

Или если брать по-другому, то `map[row][col]` - это массив массивов чисел, где первый индекс это индекс массива в массиве массивов чисел, а второй индекс - индекс элемента в массиве чисел.